# How to solve error "Field delimiter ',' found while expecting record delimiter '\n'" while loading json data to the stage

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to "COPY INTO" command to load data from s3 to the snowflake

Below are the steps I followed to create the stage and loading file from stage to Snowflake

#### JSON file

```json
{
   "Name":"Umesh",
   "Desigantion":"Product Manager",
   "Location":"United Kingdom"
}
```

```sql
create or replace stage emp_json_stage
url='s3://mybucket/emp.json'
credentials=(aws_key_id='my id' aws_secret_key='my key');

# create the table with variant
CREATE TABLE emp_json_raw (
  json_data_raw VARIANT
);

#load data from stage to snowflake

COPY INTO emp_json_raw from @emp_json_stage;
```

I am getting below error

> Field delimiter ',' found while expecting record delimiter '\n' File
> 'emp.json', line 2, character 18 Row 2, column
> "emp_json_raw"["JSON_DATA_RAW":1]

I am using a simple JSON file, and I don't understand this error.

What causes it and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File format is not specified and is defaulting to CSV format hence the error.

Try this:

```
COPY INTO emp_json_raw 
from @emp_json_stage
file_format=(TYPE=JSON);
```

There are other options too that can be specified with `file_format` other than `TYPE`. Refer the documentation here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#type-json

Answer (score 2):

try:

file_format = (type = csv field_optionally_enclosed_by='"')

The default settings do not expect the " wrapping around your data.
So you could strip all the " or ... just set the  field_optionally_enclosed_by to a ".  This does mean if your data has " in it things get messy.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/getting-started-tutorial-copy-into.html

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html#type-csv

Answer (score 0):

Also have a standard practice to mention type of file either it could be CSV, JSON ,AVRO , Parquet etc.
[image]

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a file format in snowflake.

```
create or replace file format my_csv_format
  type = csv
  record_delimiter = '\n'
  field_delimiter = ','
  skip_header = 1
  null_if = ('NULL', 'null')
  empty_field_as_null = true
  FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '0x22'
```

If you get the error - "end of record reached while expected to parse column" while trying load csv file to snowflake db",
then do

```
ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = None
```